# Is the a point to collecting coins other than using them at the slot machine?

Tags: sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing

Is the a point to collecting coins other than using them at the slot machine?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you playing [Sonic & Sega All Stars Racing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_%26_Sega_All-Stars_Racing), or [Sonic & All Stars Racing: Transformed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_%26_All-Stars_Racing_Transformed)? The names are confusing enough, and they're too long for our tag format, I just wanna be sure we got the tag right on this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, coins cannot be used for anything else.